# AspNetCore.Mvc.Core Version Mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm attempting to write a unit test for a Controller extension method, but during the Test project's build process I receive the following error message.

`MyControllerExtensionsTests.cs(17, 26): [CS1705] Assembly 'MyApp.RestApi' with identity 'MyApp.RestApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'`

Both projects declare `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` in their `.csproj` files.  I've tried deleting `bin` and `obj` folders.  How is one project resolving to `Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.0.0` and another `Mvc.Core, Version 2.1.1.0`?

Comment: can you change the version in `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` tag in `.csproj` and check?

Comment: @karthickj25 No, the problem is not the framework version

Comment: The actual problem is the NuGet packages you are using among the projects. One targets 2.1.1 and the other 2.1.0

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, The `Version` property was missing from `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`, which somehow was auto resolving to `2.1.0`.  Upgrading the package to `2.1.1` through Nuget wasn't setting the version property, causing the version to remain at `2.1.0`.  Manually setting the version in `.csproj` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

The issue noted below has been fixed & you should be able to benefit from implicit package versioning and reference like below without providing the version number of the package.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

**Original Answer**

This issue is because of the Implicit Versioning that was introduced for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage. With implicit versioning the sdk decides the version & it resolved it as 2.1.1

However, it was resolving to version 2.1 for the nunit test project. Specifying the version number for the nunit project like `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1"/>` and performing `dotnet restore` helped resolve this issue.

There is a ticket for this issue in github and this behavior around implicit versioning could change in future - https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6430 & https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/1.0/sdk/1.0-rc3-implicit-package-refs.md

Answer (score 22):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

I had the same issue, after add this line to unit test project, it start pick right version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.